Micronaut - load configs under multiple names in multi maven module project
I'm trying to split up a micronaut project into multiple maven modules so I can have separate smaller executables for pub/sub workers.
Layout now has three modules

Api
Core
Workers

Workers and Api depend on Core.
I imagine Workers and Api would each have their own set of application.yml files (and application-env.yml files), but there's shared configuration - eg the database resources, that would continue living in Core
So I'm trying to figure out how to share that configuration -- I've been trying to convince micronaut to load files named "core" in the same way and in addition to "application" with a service-loader triggered PropertySourceLoader subclassed to ignore "application" passed in and use "core" instead but it seems quite awkward.
Has anyone solved this in a good way? I know environments so I could have "core" environment set and load "application-core.yml" but that also doesn't feel quite right.
Update:
This seems to work and not break anything else. I've got to do some more experiments to see if this is the right order in the loading process.
public class CoreYamlLoader implements PropertySourceLoader, Ordered, Toggleable {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CoreYamlLoader.class);
  private final YamlPropertySourceLoader yamlLoader;

  public CoreYamlLoader() {
    yamlLoader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader();
  }


  @Override
  public Optional<PropertySource> load(String resourceName, ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
    return yamlLoader.load("core", resourceLoader);
  }

  @Override
  public Optional<PropertySource> loadEnv(String resourceName, ResourceLoader resourceLoader, ActiveEnvironment activeEnvironment) {
    return yamlLoader.loadEnv("core", resourceLoader, activeEnvironment);
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, Object> read(String name, InputStream input) throws IOException {
    // never called
    return Collections.emptyMap();
  }

  @Override
  public int getOrder() {
    return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 100;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
  }
}

